Is a user allowed to upvote all the questions they answer to so that they become hot questions?
In principle, I don't see why one would not be allowed to upvote or downvote whatever they want.
However, what if this is done in order to try to get all the questions, which you answer to, a hot question, and so get more upvotes to the answer? Should this be prevented? Is there any rule about this behavior?
(Clearly, the reason why they upvote all the questions they answer to here is just an assumption, it might be just a big coincidence that the answerer thinks all the questions are good. But for the sake of argument, let's assume that's the reason).
I am quite sure that questions that get upvotes and visits quickly can become hot questions more quickly. I've noticed this pattern in the past. The algorithm to make a question hot clearly considers the number of visits and upvotes. (Feel free to provide details about this in the comments or answers.)
Why am I concerned?

Some bad or not so good questions get upvoted
The user might get a reputation very quickly by gaming the system

In the past, I might have upvoted a few times with the intent to make a question hot, because I thought it deserved, but what if this is done continuously, every time you answer a question? I don't think this is right.
If this was allowed, then I should also be allowed to downvote whatever I think doesn't deserve to be a hot question or I could downvote anyway because I think the question is not good enough and you cannot say that I'm downvoting to prevent a question to become hot because you cannot read my mind.

"The algorithm to make a question hot clearly considers the number of visits and upvotes." actually: total number of answers, scores of posts, and question age.

Yes, total number of answers and question age are also contributing factors, I'd have said, but I'd think that views also count, although that post says otherwise. That's an old post, so maybe things have changed? That answer also says that questions with less than 8 hours are excluded, but I think I've already seen questions with less than 8 hours being included. I could be wrong though.

I'm not 100% sure of the answer, but I think the answer should be a stackexchange-wide one, not one just for AI.SE?
My initial thought however, is that I don't think it should be frowned upon to upvote questions you answer to, even if you do that extremely consistently. The motivation behind it that you imply in your question might not be ideal... but that's not the only possible motivation that would lead to the same behaviour. For example, I think that the mere fact that I bother to answer a question at all would more often than not also imply I think the question is good (enough).

I can give you examples of when a question, which is off-topic or not of very good quality, was most likely upvoted by following the behaviour I described. Maybe the user doesn't know the question is off-topic (which unlikely given that in the case I have in mind they have been around for a long time), but I still think that allowing users to constantly upvote questions they answer to is a bit "dangerous". In my view, there should be a limit, like you can upvote only say 2 questions you answer to in 1 week.

There's already a limit for downvoting or upvoting posts of a single user to prevent revenge or "thank you" voting, so I don't see why we should also not prevent a behaviour that is trying to game the system. So, let me be clear, it's fine to upvote questions you answer to, but you should not upvote everything. You need to assess what is really good. It's almost never the case that all questions deserve an upvote and I'd bet money that this is not just a coincidence.

So, what are the examples of questions that are off-topic or not of very good quality that were most likely upvoted by the behavior you described?

When you look at the formula for Hot Network Question (HNQ) scores, you'll see that one additional vote on the question is not very powerful in influencing whether or not the question becomes an HNQ.
Furthermore, if a user felt that a question was worth spending time and energy to answer it, then it's not unlikely that they'll feel it was a worthwhile enough question to get an upvote.
In conclusion, it's not going to be practical to stop people from upvoting questions that they answer, and even if we did that, it wouldn't make much of an impact on whether or not a question becomes an HNQ. Also, if you don't allow people to upvote the questions that they answer, you might lose some answerers as some people might become less motivated to write answers if their right to vote on the question is taken away.
